# Why my regex is not working in JS?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a piece of regex which works fine in regex101 but when I try to put it in js function it doesn't work, meaning it gives wrong results.

I need value of `data-sh-content` and `data-sh-attr`. For some reason I can not use dom manipulation. It have to be using regex.

```
var content = '<p><!-- content block start --></p><div class="content-block mceNonEditable" style="color: #999999;" data-sh-attr="%20color%3D%22%23999999%22" data-sh-content="%5Bgrid%5D%3Cp%3Elkjlk%3C%2Fp%3E%5B%2Fgrid%5D%5Bgrid%5D%3Cp%3Elkjlkj%3C%2Fp%3E%5B%2Fgrid%5D"><div class="toolbar"><button class="edit-content-block">Edit</button><button class="remove-content-block">Delete</button></div><div class="content"><div class="grid col-md-6" data-sh-attr="" data-sh-content="%3Cp%3Elkjlk%3C%2Fp%3E"><p>lkjlk</p></div><div class="grid col-md-6" data-sh-attr="" data-sh-content="%3Cp%3Elkjlkj%3C%2Fp%3E"><p>lkjlkj</p></div><div';

console.log('before restoring shortcode: %s', content);

var content_block_pattern = /<p><!-- content block start -->[\S\s]+?content-block[\S\s]+?data-sh-attr="([\s\S]+?)"[\s\S]+?data-sh-content="([\s\S]+?)"[\S\s]+?<!-- content block end --><\/p>/g;
content = content.replace(content_block_pattern, function(attributes, content){
    attributes = decodeURIComponent(attributes);
    content = decodeURIComponent(content);
    console.log("attributes %s", attributes);
    console.log("Conents: %s", content);
    return '[block '+attributes+']'+content+'[/block]';
});

console.log('after restoring shortcodes: %s', content);
```

It gives wrong result. See in the console.
While I have the same pattern that I used in regex101 and it works fine https://regex101.com/r/hF1wE3/1

Here is a jsfiddle for you to work on http://jsfiddle.net/yLm3xwrw/

Comment: Why are you using regular expressions on HTML?

Comment: Read my question. I have no choice.

Comment: Nothing in your question indicates that you have no choice. You are sitting in front of JavaScript, which is built into advanced HTML DOM parsers, *of course* you have a choice.

Comment: `[\S\s]`? Why not `.`?

Comment: @Andrea Because `.` does not match newlines.

Comment: Downvoters, please provide reason for downvotes so I can edit my question. Thanks! Weather one should use dom parser or regex to parse is not in the context of this question as I pointed on the question.

Comment: "Parser" or "regex" is not a decision between equal ways of doing HTML processing. It's not a matter of preference, it's not 50/50. Parsers are the right choice in 99% of the cases, regex might be the right choice in 1% of the cases, very probably less. Regex is what you use when you have exhausted every other alternative. So "not in the context of this question" is bullshit, plain and simple.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

replace call back function first argument is all, not the first matched string. Fixed code is below.

```
content = content.replace(content_block_pattern, function(all, attributes, content){
    attributes = decodeURIComponent(attributes);
    content = decodeURIComponent(content);
    console.log("attributes %s", attributes);
    console.log("Conents: %s", content);
    return '[block '+attributes+']'+content+'[/block]';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regular expressions to process HTML. *Especially not* when you are actually working with the most sophisticated HTML parser on the planet.

```
// parse HTML string into a DOM node
var content = '<p><!-- content block start --></p><div class="content-block mceNonEditable" style="color: #999999;" data-sh-attr="%20color%3D%22%23999999%22" data-sh-content="%5Bgrid%5D%3Cp%3Elkjlk%3C%2Fp%3E%5B%2Fgrid%5D%5Bgrid%5D%3Cp%3Elkjlkj%3C%2Fp%3E%5B%2Fgrid%5D"><div class="toolbar"><button class="edit-content-block">Edit</button><button class="remove-content-block">Delete</button></div><div class="content"><div class="grid col-md-6" data-sh-attr="" data-sh-content="%3Cp%3Elkjlk%3C%2Fp%3E"><p>lkjlk</p></div><div class="grid col-md-6" data-sh-attr="" data-sh-content="%3Cp%3Elkjlkj%3C%2Fp%3E"><p>lkjlkj</p></div>';
var container = document.createElement("DIV");
container.innerHTML = content;

// helper that can process an attribute of a node
function processAttribute(elem, attrib, func) {
    var val = elem.getAttribute(attrib);
    if (val) elem.setAttribute(attrib, func(val));
}

// now processing the attributes is straight-forward
var contentSel = ".content-block, .content-block *[data-sh-attr], content-block *[data-sh-content]",
    contentElems = container.querySelectorAll(contentSel),
    i;

for (i = 0; i < contentElems.length; i++) {
    processAttribute(contentElems[i], "data-sh-attr", decodeURIComponent);
    processAttribute(contentElems[i], "data-sh-content", decodeURIComponent);
}

console.log(container.innerHTML);
```

I suppose in reality you already have DOM nodes, in which case the parsing step would not be necessary.

Comment: This answer is out of the context. My question was why the given regex is not giving expected result while the regex is seem to be correct on the regex101 link I provided.

Comment: @Sisir "For some reason" is not a strong enough explanation. You work with JavaScript, I showed you working JavaScript, so explain why you can't use it.